# Array of IDs, Restangular, .several()

Tags: javascript, restangular

I am trying to fetch a series of objects from my Node.js-based, MongoDB instance using Restangular; however, I am not able to guarantee the number of objects I wish to grab by ID will always be the same.

To demonstrate, here is a code snippet of the principle:

```
Restangular
    .several('users',
        userList[0], userList[1], userList[2], userList[3], userList[4],
        userList[5], userList[6], userList[7], userList[8], userList[9])
    .get().then(function (users) { //...
```

`userList` is an array of IDs passed in as a part of a method:

```
requestUsersById = function (userList) { //...
```

The problem is that I cannot guarantee the size of the array. Is there a way to pass an array of IDs using Restangular? Or, am I just stuck making separate requests for each?

The ideal result would be something like:

```
Restangular
    .several('users', userList)
    .get().then(function (users) { //...
```

Answer (score 1):

The Restangular API doesn't seem to natively support this, but I believe you can accomplish what you're trying to do by making using the [`apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

In this case, you'd append the name of the collection `users` to the head of your `userList` array. Try this out:

```
// Store the userList in a new array to preserve the initial list 
// (not sure if you use it somewhere else
var usersQuery = userList;

// Shift the collection name to be the first parameter in the array
usersQuery.unshift("users");

// Perform the Restangular call
Restangular
    .several.apply(null,usersQuery)
    .get().then(function (users) { //...
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach; wouldn't it be better to apply to a regular `get` in that case?

Comment: Referring to a standard js HTTP `GET` request? There's no meaningful performance difference, as far as I'm aware. It mostly will just come down to your preference in regards to how you want to request and handle the data.